# Dell D610 6.5 CentOS Installation - Undetected Network Adapters

Tags: networking, centos, wifi, laptop

I've spent the better part of the day attempting to install CentOS 6.5 on an older Dell D610 laptop, using everything from a Minimal Install to the Full DVD.

After multiple attempts I was able to finally install the OS, but find both the ethernet and wifi adapter remain undetected.

Labels on this laptop are unreadable and I cannot determine what adapters are in fact installed. Is there any easy solution to resolving this problem, or am I better served re-installing another distro?

Answer (score 1):

You can check what devices your laptop has by doing

```
#  lspci | grep net
```

and do

```
 #  ip link
```

to see what interfaces you have and their status.

Check if you have files like ifcfg-eth0 under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
if you do, make sure that the ONBOOT parameter is set to yes.

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

Once you have decided what you want, static or dynamic IP address, you can configure your interface(s).

Also 
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-files.html
is a good page to visit.