# Dell Latitude D630 Wireless Problem on Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, wifi

I've recently acquired a used Dell Latitude D630 and have put Mint on it. Everything seems to be operational except for the wireless. First, I don't know if the wireless card actually works (Ethernet does) and if it does, Mint is not recognizing it. I haven't figured out how to identify the card in Linux, so I am clueless as to what driver I actually need to download and install. Thanks in advance!

---

P.S., just saw [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117376/dell-d610-6-5-centos-installation-undetected-network-adapters) and [this page](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=129533), and here is my results:

```
> lspci | grep net
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)

> ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:70:ae:40:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

> inxi -N
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY driver: b43-pci-bridge
           Card-2: Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express driver: tg3
```

Not sure how this helps me, but I'm sure someone out there knows how to find what I need (and/or much appreciated if you can tell me what part I need to be looking at). Thanks!

Comment: Please consider , if you have any wifi driver and want to install new , you have to remove them and install new driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fixed it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232532/cant-get-wireless-working-on-12-10-and-dell-latitude-d630)! Only difference is that the installation told me to use `apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` instead.